# Event for gps on/off state change

Tags: android, gps

I want to listen a GPS state changes in my app, is there in android any intent-action which I can use in a broadCast receiver like an `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` for network-state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver for listening to Intent Action `PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION`. 
or you can try this snippet

```
GpsStatus.Listener gpsListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
                    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
                        if( event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX){
                            showMessageDialog("GPS fixed");
                        }
                    }
             };
```

OR

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.addGpsStatusListener(new android.location.GpsStatus.Listener()
{
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
    {
        switch(event)
        {
        case GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            // do your tasks
            break;
        case GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            // do your tasks
            break;
        }
    }
});
```