# Calling a funtion on gps button switching in android

Tags: android, gps

I have written code to open gps setting when it is off. But I need to call a function after gps button is set to ON. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When GPS button changed, system will send a broadcast to notify that event, so
add `permission` and `receiver` in `manifest` like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".LocationChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

then create `LocationChangeReceiver` like this:

```
public class LocationChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            // gps enabled
        } else {
            // gps disabled
        }
    }
}
```

Or use `onGpsStatusChanged` callback like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614149/2782538

Hope it helps.