# Android DeviceCare disabling GPS in custom app

Tags: android, gps

We recently received an update to our company phones bringing the OS software to  Android Version 9 - Kernel 4.4.153-15480849.

There appears to be an entire app called DeviceCare that is sporadically disabling GPS entirely after a period of time.  We have not been able to nail down when or why this is happening on some phones.

We also noticed that the ability to place apps in an Unmonitored Apps area to avoid  the OS from disrupting functionality like GPS is no longer available.

We have a custom app that tracks GPS location every 5 minutes by sending lat/long to a remote server script via the web using variables calling a URL. That is now sporadically stopping GPS tracking.

Can anyone provide some insight on a workaround or some criteria when DeviceCare disables GPS?  Does it reach a battery level of X% and then shutdown for example?

I searched for documentation and find nothing.

Comment: Its not going to have documentation-  it isn't a part of Android.  its a Samsung app for its devices that acts as anti-malware (or at least that's its intention).  It isn't going to publish its algorithms.  I'd advise disabling that app if its causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Device Care](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-use-device-care/) is an optimization function on Samsung Galaxy devices running Android 9.0. The main purpose of this utility app is to optimize the user's device `Battery, Storage, Memory and Security information`.

Just like every other settings on a device, actions provided by Device Care are primarily initiated by the user. Let's say your app consumes lots of memory or battery usage, Device Care can give the user the option to kill or force stop your app. And also if it noticed that the phone's GPS is turned on, a good optimization option for the user would be to turn it off.

> Hence it is left for your custom app to [listen for network changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611824/event-for-gps-on-off-state-change) and always
>   notify the user about the consequences involved when their GPS is
>   turned off.